How to get Invoke Input Authorization string in Tibco BW 6
I found a Tibco BW 6 Invoke Process to which I need the authorization token string that is in the input of the operation. Does anyone know how I can simply grab the authorization string and pass as a stored variable?
InvokeImage
I initially tried to use a mapper to pull that value out but it is only mapping the output of the Invoke Activity.

Sorry, your question is not clear to me. Do you want to set the authorization token while using the Invoke Process ? Or do you want to access the authorization token that was used with the call that triggered your process execution ?

I want to access the authorization token that was used with the call that triggered the process.

The authorization token that was used in the call that triggered your process execution is in the Authorization HTTP Header and you should be able to see it in the Data Source tab of the Mapper.
You can either just reuse that header or decode it and extract the needed information.
To decode it you will need to use the base64-to-string function like below:
tib:base64-to-string($get/httpHeaders/tns1:httpHeaders/Authorization)

